# npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered (cordova-plugin-app-event broken symbolic link)

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

my problem is found in the title. I try to open an Ionic project, which uses *ionic-native/barcode-scanner*. But if I try to install anything with npm, this error occurs:

> npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access
>   '/*path/to*/node_modules/cordova-plugin-app-event'

I found that error in the internet, but no working solution. Deleting the *node_modules*-Directory and doing `npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts` doesn't help.

Here's what I found out with the file command:

> file cordova-plugin-app-event
>   cordova-plugin-app-event: broken symbolic link to cordova-plugin-app-event

So the `npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts`-command always creates a broken symbolic link.

I'm on an Arch Linux derivate and npm is installed through pacman. *NPM* is version 6.4.1, *Ionic* is 4.3.1 . I also tried to re-install *NPM* and *node.js* in pacman.

There's also that warning:

> [WARN] Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it's too old--using
>   global CLI.

Trying to solve that with `npm remove ionic --save-dev` or `npm install ionic@latest --save` again throws that symlink error.

I can't continue working without solving the error, so I'd be very grateful for all kind of help.